# facebook like and share plugin distorts the page while they're loading on chrome (both desktop and ipad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook

note: i've tested this on chrome with both desktop (mac) and ipad.

i've noticed that on my pages, when the facebook like/share plugin loads, it distorts the page ...like everything below the social plugins is pushed down 1010 pixels (i've paused the execution and checked the height) for about 1 second and then it jumps back up and the buttons are loaded. has anyone ever experienced this before?

i tried adding heights to the div like this:

but it's still happening.

i have this right after `<body>`:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXX',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and then the actual code on the page is:

```
<div class="social-share">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.whatever.com/page.html" data-width="50" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
</div>
```

with css code:

```
.social-share{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
}
```

i checked the source code right when it happens and it shows me this:

```
iframe[Attributes Style] {
  width: 50px;
  height: 1000px;
...
}
```

which is the facebook iframe. what could be causing this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/486785918148603/

Comment: Oops! Thanks for that. I thought I was the only one. I noticed that `overflow: hidden` fixes it but bumps the button a few pixels up.

Comment: `overflow` will hide the optional sharing popup.