# Facebook "like" button no longer overlays content (pushes content instead)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I added the Facebook "like" button to my page a few weeks ago, and everything was OK. Clicking the button would show an overlay with options to share.

Now, without any action on my part, it seems like the button has changed its behavior (I guess Facebook pushes some changes to its API?)

**Here's the button unclicked:**

[image]

**Here's the button clicked:**

[image]

---

Not only was the content pushed down, but the button appears to have become block displayed. This behavior has only been noticed in the last few days. Anyone else experience this?

**EDIT:** It's also worth noting at the same behavior is experienced on their documentation example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: There’s currently problems with the Like button, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046247/facebook-like-and-share-plugin-distorts-the-page-while-theyre-loading-on-chrome – might as well be related to that.

Comment: Hey, thanks, that's super helpful. Annoying that this kind of thing gets through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was eventually sorted out when Facebook fixed their injected HTML.